# match EOF but go to endless loop in flex

Tags: regex, match, lex, flex-lexer, eof

I need to match EOF in flex

this is the main error part of my code lex.l

```
%{
%}
%%
<<EOF>> {printf("match EOF\n");}
%%
int main(){
    yylex();
}
```

i use

```
flex lex.l  ;  gcc lex.yy.c -o lex.exe -lfl ; lex.exe < text
```

to execute

and this is my text file  just one line

```
abc(no \n or \r at the end of file)
```

but when I execute lex.exe it goes into **endless loop** and output **infinite line of  "match EOF\n"**

How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to return something from the `EOF` action; otherwise, `flex` will continue to attempt to read the input, and everytime it does it will find that it is at the `EOF`, causing it to execute your action again.

In fact, you should always return `0` from an `<<EOF>>` pattern, if you are working with `yacc/bison`, because that's how you signal the parser that it has reached the end of input. However, in most cases it is not actually necessary to explicitly do anything because `return 0` is the default `EOF` action.

Comment: or `yyterminate()`